# how to convert xml document object to string?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have xml that I have in a string. I want to change some attributes in it.
So what I have done is

```
var xml //contains xml  
parser = new DOMParser()
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml")
xmlDoc.setAttribute("name", "random")
```

Now the xmlDoc has the required changes. But how do I get the string representation of the xml again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to serialize your `xmlDoc` back to XML once you have made the changes:

```
var s = new XMLSerializer();
var newXmlStr = s.serializeToString(xmlDoc);
```

Now you can do what you need to do with the string of updated XML, overwrite your `xml` variable, or send it to the server, or whatever...

See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) for further info

Comment: Works. Thanks. Much appreciated. :)