# how to get xml document out of html document

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I am having trouble retrieving a complete xml document in Chrome when using 
  `xmlDOM = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);` to initially create the document.
once I create the DOM I then add the elements to it dynamically

```
function setUsersSearchVariables(_firstName,_lastName,_Username,_Email,_Phone,_US_Emp_Pub,_US_Both,_CS_InAct_Act,_CS_Both, _companyName, _accountType, _tAll)
{
    try
    {
        var dataDoc = new DataDocument();

        dataDoc.mode = 'SET_SEARCH_USER_SESSION_VARIABLES';
        dataDoc.appendKeyElement('COMPANY_NAME', _companyName);
        dataDoc.appendKeyElement('FIRST_NAME',_firstName);
        dataDoc.appendKeyElement('LAST_NAME',_lastName);
        dataDoc.appendKeyElement('USER_NAME',_Username);
        dataDoc.appendKeyElement('EMAIL',_Email);
        dataDoc.appendKeyElement('PHONE',_Phone);
        dataDoc.appendKeyElement('US_EMP_PUB',_US_Emp_Pub);
        dataDoc.appendKeyElement('US_BOTH',_US_Both);
        dataDoc.appendKeyElement('CS_INACT_ACT',_CS_InAct_Act);
        dataDoc.appendKeyElement('CS_BOTH', _CS_Both);
        dataDoc.appendKeyElement('ACCOUNT_TYPE', _accountType);
        dataDoc.appendKeyElement('TYPE_BOTH', _tAll);
        dataDoc.sendToServer();
        return false;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert('Block: setUsersSearchVariables\n'+e.message);
        return false;
    }
}
  var rootNodeName = 'POST_DATA';
    var modeAttrName = 'MODE';

var appendKeyElementRef = function (key, value) {
    try {
        this.validateDoc();

        var keyNode = this.doc.createElement(key);

        if (value.toString() != '') {
            var cdataNode = this.doc.createCDATASection(value.toString());
            keyNode.appendChild(cdataNode);
        }

        var rootNode = this.doc.getElementsByTagName(rootNodeName)[0];
        //var rootNode = this.getElementsByTagName(rootNodeName)[0];
        rootNode.appendChild(keyNode);
    }
    catch (ex) {
        alert('Block: appendKeyElementRef\n' + ex.message);
    }
};
```

The data document:

```
function DataDocument()
{
    // Member properties
    this.mode = '';
    this.gcNames = null;
    this.target = null;
    this.callbackControlId = null;
    this.callbackId = null;
    this.section = null;
    this.sessionOutTime = 0;
    this.sessionOutWarningTime = 0;
    this.browserType = getBrowserType();
    this.doc = createDoc(this.browserType);
}

// Member functions of DataDocument class

// Type : Public
// To load string data into DataDocument 
DataDocument.prototype.load = loadRef;

// Type : Private
// To check DataDocument for root node
// If root node does not exist, it will be created
DataDocument.prototype.validateDoc = validateDocRef;

// Type : Public
// To append a key-value pair with the DataDocument
DataDocument.prototype.appendKeyElement = appendKeyElementRef;

// Type : Public
// To append a control as an element node with the DataDocument
DataDocument.prototype.appendControlElement = appendControlElementRef;

// Type : Public
// To append a container's child controls as element nodes with the DataDocument
DataDocument.prototype.appendContainerElement = appendContainerElementRef;

// Type : Private
// To append an element node with the DataDocument
DataDocument.prototype.appendElementNode = appendElementNodeRef;

// Type : Private
// To append the MODE attribure for the DataDocument root node
DataDocument.prototype.appendModeAttribute = appendModeAttributeRef;

// Type : Private
// To append the SENDER attribure for the DataDocument root node
DataDocument.prototype.appendSenderAttribute = appendSenderAttributeRef;

// Type : Private
// To append the SECTION attribure for the DataDocument root node
DataDocument.prototype.appendSectionAttribute = appendSectionAttributeRef;

// Type : Public
// To get the value of element node by element id
DataDocument.prototype.getValueByElementId = getValueByElementIdRef;

// Type : Public
// To get the value of key-value node by key name
DataDocument.prototype.getValueByKeyName = getValueByKeyNameRef;

// Type : Public
// To get the DataDocument content as string
DataDocument.prototype.toString = toStringRef;

// Type : Private
// To get the DataDocument content as string to send for callback
// It will add the MODE and SENDER attributes before generate the string
DataDocument.prototype.toStringForCallback = toStringForCallbackRef;

// Type : Public
// Raise the callback from client side with the DataDocument as content
DataDocument.prototype.sendToServer = sendToServerRef;

DataDocument.prototype.getElementsByTagName = getElementsByTagNameRef;
DataDocument.prototype.getElementsByTagNameInternal = getElementsByTagNameInternalRef;
```

I read that the `document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);` creates an html document. I then tried to get the XML with `this.doc.documentElement.innerHTML;`. That gave me an Html string without the correct root node and the mode.

The innerHtml that we have in chrome

> `"<COMPANY_NAME/><FIRST_NAME><![CDATA[Name]]></FIRST_NAME><LAST_NAME/><USER_NAME/><EMAIL/><PHONE><![CDATA[(___)___-____]]></PHONE><US_EMP_PUB/><US_BOTH><![CDATA[True]]></US_BOTH><CS_INACT_ACT/><CS_BOTH><![CDATA[True]]></CS_BOTH><ACCOUNT_TYPE/><TYPE_BOTH><![CDATA[True]]></TYPE_BOTH>"`

The XML that I need should be like this:

```
<POST_DATA SENDER="CLIENT" MODE="SET_SEARCH_USER_SESSION_VARIABLES"><COMPANY_NAME/><FIRST_NAME><![CDATA[chris]]></FIRST_NAME><LAST_NAME/><USER_NAME/><EMAIL/><PHONE><![CDATA[(___)___-____]]></PHONE><US_EMP_PUB/><US_BOTH><![CDATA[True]]></US_BOTH><CS_INACT_ACT/><CS_BOTH><![CDATA[True]]></CS_BOTH><ACCOUNT_TYPE/><TYPE_BOTH><![CDATA[True]]></TYPE_BOTH></POST_DATA>
```

So this works if I use IE with the ActiveXObject , however It does not work when using Chrome. I have read everything I can find in reguards to the HTML DOM and the XML DOM , I just cannot figure this out.I hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have posted incomplete code that doesn't actually create the root `<POST_DATA/>` element anywhere.

The correct invocation would be something like (see the [`createDocument` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createDocument)):

```
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument ('', 'POST_DATA', null);
```

To serialize XML you shouldn't use innerHTML: [how to convert xml document object to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822446/how-to-convert-xml-document-object-to-string)

```
var s = new XMLSerializer();
var docStr = s.serializeToString(xmlDoc); // returns "<POST_DATA/>" for the xmlDoc above
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this today.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Nick I found the solution I already had. I just needed to serialize the document.

```
 return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(thisDoc);
```

I may have a job for another week or two now whew!! Thanks Nick once again.